# adding delete button to listview in android

Tags: android

i have a list view and i want to mimic the functionality of 
UITableViewEditingStyle in iphone . 
I want the listview to have a delete button and when the user clicks the deleting button, that particular row should get deleted not only from the database but also from the listview.

I am using ListActivity.

Thank you for your help.

Here is the code that i am using

import android.R.anim;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class EditSiteList extends ListActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.editsitelist);
    HandleDatabase db = new HandleDatabase(null,null,null);
    String names[] = db.getSites();
    ListAdapter la = new Arraydapter(this,R.layout.editsiterow,R.id.sitename,names);
    HandleDatabase hd = new HandleDatabase(null, null, null);
            hd.getSitesCursor(), new String[]{"name"}, android.R.id.);
    setListAdapter(la);
}
```

Comment: Have you got some code that you started to implement this with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement your own `ListAdapter` with this functionality plus you have to decide where to situate the Delete button. At least I did so in my project when I had found that Android has no equivalents of this iPhone feature. In your `ListAdapter` you should delete the items from the `ListView` and from the DB manually.

Comment: too bad android does not have this feature. there are so many features that the iphone has and android does not.... i mean for the best mobile os in the world, android really needs to improve.